# How to to apply a checker texture to a bended plane (seamless backdrop)?

Tags: texturing

I want the pattern regular and to scale the plane if necessary. Yet the pattern
is irregular (rectangles instead of squares at the bottom). Applied the bevel modifier and all transformations to no avail or
even worse results.

### [image: pic]
[image]

Edit:

After unwrapping and applying some proposed node changes. Now only the curve remains to fix:
[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way that works fine but if you don't find it, you could simply give your object a *Curve* modifier in order to bend it and unwrap it in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is `unwrap`?. I've applied the nodes. It's worse. Guess that's why the unwrap is needed before.

Comment: In Edit mode, select All then press 'U' to unwrap. Suggest you read up on the UV editor!

Comment: In Edit mode, select all and press U > Unwrap. It will indicate how the texture is supposed to be projected on the surface. You can open a UV Editor window if you want to see the UV